# Angular 6 ngx-mask plugin, multiple masks on same input field

Tags: javascript, angular, masking

So i use this plugin https://github.com/JsDaddy/ngx-mask to mask an input field dynamically (while user is typing). So for example if my mask only accepts 123 and they type abc nothing will happen. The problem I am having is I need two masks on the same input field so I need for example 123 and abc to both be accepted not just one or the other. Here is my code sample following the docs at the link above.

```
<input id="main-office-phone"type="phone" minlength="10" prefix="+1 " mask="(000)-000-0000">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work

```
<input id="main-office-phone"type="phone" minlength="10" prefix="+1 " mask="(AAA)-AAA-AAAA">
```

Comment: Why do you think so?

Comment: check the source code export const initialConfig: IConfig = {   patterns: {
        '0': {
            pattern: new RegExp('\\d'),
        },
        '9': {
            pattern: new RegExp('\\d'),
            optional: true,
        },
        X: {
            pattern: new RegExp('\\d'),
            symbol: '*',
        },
        A: {
            pattern: new RegExp('[a-zA-Z0-9]'),
        },

Answer (score 0):

use this for example

```
<input id="main-office-phone"type="phone" minlength="10" prefix="+1 " mask="AAA AAA AAA||(000)-000-0000">
```

You must use the double pipe "||" symbol to separate the two different masks you would like to use.